# Firebase verification email React

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, react-hooks, email-verification

Try to make a login system with firebase .When I sign Up , data store firebase and give me verification mail,its useless  . I need first give me mail when I confirmed then data store firebase .It's perfectly work if I can't use verification ,perfectly store data and work fine .when i use verification its give me email and store data same time its not waiting my confirmation..

```
const SignUp = () => {


    const [user, setUser] = useState({

        isSignIn: false,
        name: '',
        email: '',
        password: '',
        confirmPassword: '',
        error: '',
        passwordError: '',
        success: false


    })


    //check function  password  & confirm password equal or not 

    const isPasswordConfirmed = (password, confimPassword) => {

        if (password && confimPassword && password === confimPassword) return true;
        return false;
    }


    const handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault()

        if (!isPasswordConfirmed(user.password, user.password_confirm)) {

            let newuser = { ...user }
            newuser.passwordError = "password not matching"
            setUser(newuser)

            return;
        }

    //   user.sendEmailVerification()
               
      



      const newname=  firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, 
 user.password)
    
         
            .then((userCredential) => {
                // Signed in 

              
               
                var user = userCredential.user;
                
                 user.sendEmailVerification()  //mail verification firebase 
              
                let newuser = { ...user }
                newuser.error = ""
                
                setUser(newuser)

                // UserInfoPass(user.name)

                // ...
            })
            
            .catch((error) => {
                var errorCode = error.code;
                var errorMessage = error.message;
                user.isSignIn = false

                let newuser = { ...user }
                newuser.error = errorMessage
                setUser(newuser)




            });



    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been covered frequently before: Firebase Authentication doesn't require email verification before signing the user in. Instead you can check the user's verification status in your application code (both front-end code, back-end code, and in Firebase's security rules), to ensure they can only use the app once they've verified their email address.

Alternatively, you can [use an email link to sign in](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/email-link-auth) to combine the email verification and authentication in a single step.

For more on this see:

- [How to check if Firebase user's email is verified before signing in to React web app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64574514/how-to-check-if-firebase-users-email-is-verified-before-signing-in-to-react-web)
- [Is there a way to verify a signed up email?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65157604/is-there-a-way-to-verify-a-signed-up-email/65158707#65158707)
- [Only let pre-verified users log into Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57343031/only-let-pre-verified-users-log-into-firebase/57343047#57343047)

And many more from this [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-authentication%5D+email+verified+before+signing)

Comment: This answer is really useful.Thanks for taking the time to contribute an answer.You are really great.